# Is it mandatory using @Transactional with @Modifying in @Query delete/update/insert methods in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is it mandatory using @Transactional with @Modifying in @Query delete/update/insert methods in Spring Boot?
If it is mandatory can anyone explain why it so? By default why it is not @Transactional as other normal CRUD methods are.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM User u WHERE u.id=:id")
int delete(@Param("id") int id, @Param("userId") int userId);
```